# StaticInjectorError in Angular 2 application console when accessing

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement a sample project using Angular 2. Here I am divided different sub modules and imported in my app.module.ts. And service also I am importing from service section. And defines routes to different components. When I am running, I am getting the following error message:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserrequestService -> String]:
```

The entire error stack is as follows:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserrequestService -> String]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UserrequestService -> String]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for String!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserrequestService -> String]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UserrequestService -> String]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for String!
at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
at _createClass (core.js:21265)
at _createProviderInstance (core.js:21235)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
at zone.js:892
```

I readed about it is the problem of imporing old version of HttpModule from angular/core. And I tried to import HttpClientModule from angular/common/http. But no change in error. And HttpModule from angular/core also added. But also no change, error is still like same.

Here I am adding my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
FilterPipe
 ],
imports: [
HttpClientModule,
BrowserModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
ApprouterModule,
MaterialModule,
FlexLayoutModule,
],
 providers: [HttpClientModule],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Where have I gone wrong in my code?

Comment: where do u inject UserrequestService? Or declare it?

Comment: @sagat - I added one service into my login component.there I am using those service.

Comment: Please provide code of your modules u r using. Usually you have to delete the httpclientmodule from the providers array of your app.module.ts and add the service u want to use.

Comment: In your app.module.ts --> providers: [UserrequestService]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove HttpClientModule from providers.
Did you try to put UserrequestService in providers?
Or write service decorator like: 
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

Comment: Hi Mate. This is not an answer but a question. This should only be a comment. Also he is using angular 2, as the title says, there is no {providedIn: 'root'} object.